# SwiftUI List is extremely slow at showing actions (leading/trailing, contextMenu) when the dataset is big

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm facing performance problems using a SwiftUI `List` with lots of data. I've created a demo app just to showcase the problem with 500_000 `String`s and to show a trailing action for one of them, the CPU hits 100% for a few seconds, which is totally unusable. I also went ahead and wrapped `UITableView` to use it on SwiftUI using the same dataset (the same half a million `String`s) and the trailing action is displayed instantly.

Is there any way to speed things up on the SwiftUI `List` or is this just a limitation of the framework?

I've made it easy to test both implementations by just changing the var named `listKind`, here's the sample code:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct LargeListPerformanceProblemApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                ContentView().navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            }
        }
    }
}

enum ListKind {
    case slow
    case fast
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var listKind = ListKind.slow
    var items: [String]
    
    init() {
        self.items = (0...500_000).map { "Item \($0)" }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        switch listKind {
        case .slow:
            List {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text(item).swipeActions(edge: .trailing, allowsFullSwipe: true) {
                        Button("Print") {
                            let _ = print("Tapped")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.navigationTitle("Slow (SwiftUI List)")
        case .fast:
            FastList(items: self.items)
                .navigationTitle("Fast (UITableView Wrapper)")
        }
    }
}


// UITableView wrapper
struct FastList: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let items: [String]
    
    init(items: [String]) {
        self.items = items
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITableView {
        let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .insetGrouped)
        tableView.dataSource = context.coordinator
        tableView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return tableView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITableView, context: Context) {
        uiView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(items: items)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
        
        var items: [String]
        
        init(items: [String]) {
            self.items = items
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            self.items.count
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
            cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
            let printAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Print") { _, _, block in
                print("Tapped")
                block(true)
            }
            return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [printAction])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this on the simulator or a real device?

Comment: @JordanD It happens on both, simulator and real device (iPhone 11 Pro).

Answer (score 3):

Profiling in instruments it appears that List creates meta data for every item in order to track changes (for things like insert/delete animations).

[image: Instruments]

So even though List is optimized to avoid creating invisible rows, it still has the meta data overhead that the direct UITableView implementation doesn't incur.

One other demonstration of the overhead of List is to instead use a ScrollView/LazyVStack combination. I don't recommend this as an alternative (in addition to the visual differences, it will blow up as you scroll down the list), but because it doesn't do change tracking, it too will have a fairly quick initial display.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to profile the code. Do you know if there's any way to prevent the change tracking to speed things up? (I'm okay with loosing any animations, I'd only use the possible fix on Lists that display >= 100K of rows)

Comment: I'm not aware of any ways around it. The elephant in the room is the question: do you really need to have a list containing 100K+ rows? You could, instead, do a deferred loading list by expanding the items array as users scroll. But if users ever actually did scroll 100k lines down (and likely much sooner), they'd incur massive UI lag.

Comment: I understand that such long list are not common, but they've been fine in AppKit/UIKit because of proper cell reuse and not loading things that are not on screen. I'm working on an app that handles lots of data, all of which can be searchable, and ideally yes, everything should be able to be shown at once. I need to investigate if using Core Data and setting an appropriate `fetchBatchSize` on the `NSFetchRequest` improves things or not (I'm not sure that it even works with SwiftUI's @FetchRequest, I'll post my findings when I get to it). Either way, thanks for looking into this!

Comment: It seems to be a common topic, `List`s don't perform well at all with lots of data: https://kean.blog/post/not-list